# ant sql task error: No suitable Driver

Tags: ant

I am using the following ant sql task and its throwing "No suitable Driver exception"        java.sql.SQLException: No suitable Driver for 
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.JDBCTask.getConnection(JDBCTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.getConnection(SQLExec.java:961)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:628)

I have verified that the ojdbc6 jar is present in the location and echoing classpath also includes the location of jar.

```
<property name="jdbc.driver.jar" value="${wl.home}/server/lib/ojdbc6.jar"/>
<property name="jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
<sql driver="${jdbc.driver}"
          url="${datasource_url}"
          userid="${datasource_user}"
          password="${datasource_password}"
          src="${sqlfile}"
          output="${outfile}"
          print="true"
          onerror="abort"
          expandProperties="true">
          <classpath>
              <pathelement location="${jdbc.driver.jar}"/>
          </classpath>
</sql>
```

Comment: "*No suitable Driver for*" usually indicates a wrong JDBC URL, not a missing driver. So what *is* your URL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks. I was able to figure it out looking at the JDBCTask class - http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/JDBCTask.java. They are throwing "No suitable driver" error for any connection related issues. I was able to resolve this by providing the correct jdbc url.